# Add a new dimension to a netCDF file created by xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I have a large `Dataset` that the data assembly center wants to have a new variable `idstring` added to it, *with* a new dimension `idstring_len`.  (I don't know why they want that as a new variable, instead of as an attribute, but...)

So I have

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.Dataset()
ds['time'] = ('time', np.arange(1000))
ds['boo']  = ('time', np.randome.randn(1000))

# File is saved in here, then `open_dataset` to get it again. 

ds['idstr_len'] = ('idstr_len', 50)
ds['idstring'] = ('idstr_len', 'my_helpful_ID_string')
```

but this gives me at `ds['idstr_len'] = ...`:

```
ValueError: dimensions ('idstr_len',) must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=0
```

So I'm sure there is a good way to add a dimension post-facto to a Dataset, but I'm not sure what it is.

EDIT:  For more context, the way they suggets to do this in raw netcdf is:

```py
TRAJECTORY_STRING = 'glider-YYYYmmddTHHMM'
trajectory = nc.createDimension('traj_strlen', len(TRAJECTORY_STRING))

trajectory = nc.createVariable('trajectory',
    'S1',
    ('traj_strlen',))
```

I guess I could just do all this using the raw netcdf interface after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a dataset with a string variable to a netCDF file, xarray actually *does* create a dummy string length dimension, e.g., consider:

```
import xarray
ds = xarray.Dataset({'idstring': 'my_helpful_ID_string'})
ds.to_netcdf('mydata.nc')
```

`ncdump` reveals that the data has a dummy dimension `string20`:

```
$ ncdump mydata.nc
netcdf mydata {
dimensions:
    string20 = 20 ;
variables:
    char idstring(string20) ;
        idstring:_Encoding = "utf-8" ;
data:

 idstring = "my_helpful_ID_string" ;
}
```

This is needed because netCDF's character type only represents single characters.

Xarray doesn't give you control over this dimension name directly, but you can modify it with netCDF4 after the fact, e.g.,

```
import netCDF4
with netCDF4.Dataset('mydata.nc', 'r+') as nc:
    nc.renameDimension('string20', 'idstring_strlen')
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that works fine.  Its a bit hack-y, but so is the requirement for that format!